# CSV first cell restrictions

Tags: c#, excel, csv

If I create `csv` file (I'm doing it from C#), which contains text "**ID**" in first cell in first row, `MS Excel 2010` fails to open it, it says, file is not a valid `csv` file.
I spend a half of an hour, before I realized that problem is with that "**ID**".
Most interesting thing in this situation is, that if "**ID**" is moved to any other cell, everything works just fine.

Steps to reproduce : 
Create text file with following content:

```
ID,Name
1,Unnamed
```

Save it.Change extension to `csv`.

That's all, `MS Excel 2010` will tell you that this file is not a `csv` and will fail to open it!

What I am doing wrong?I googled for some info, but it seems, **ID** is not some kind of reserved word.

I'm running Win7Enterprisex64 and using MS Excel 2010, as I mentioned.
P.S depending on your culture settings, `csv` separator may be `,` or `;` (maybe some other characters)

Comment: This is more of an Excel problem than a programming problem... voted to move to superuser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that Excel thinks the file is a "SYLK" file.  It is a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626).

Comment: OMG, what a fail...Thanks for the link

Comment: Agreed, just encountered this issue. This is ridiculous! I spent hours trying to figure out why my process was generating corrupt files, but it was because I used ID.